# Android LinkedList ConcurrentModificationException SurfaceView Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, linked-list, surfaceview, concurrentmodification

I have a `SurfaceView` that that the user can draw multiple bitmaps to and modify (stickers). The stickers are held in a `LinkedList` that is iterated on `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` to find which sticker is being touched by the user:

```
private void setActiveSticker(float x, float y) {
    Iterator<Sticker> stickersDesc = mStickers.descendingIterator();
    while (stickersDesc.hasNext()) {
        Sticker sticker = stickersDesc.next();
        if (sticker.collider(x, y)) {
            mActiveSticker = sticker;
            mMode = MODE_DRAG;
            break;
        }
        mStickers.remove(mActiveSticker);
        mStickers.add(mActiveSticker);
    }
}
```

This `LinkedList` is also iterated to draw each one to the `Canvas` of the `SurfaceView` as they are manipulated:

```
@Override
public void draw (Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mMatrix, mPaint);

    for (Sticker sticker : mStickers) {
        sticker.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

And this is where I get a `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
09-28 08:56:41.769  19832-24370/com.example.ex E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5279
Process: com.example.ex, PID: 19832
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.LinkedList$LinkIterator.next(LinkedList.java:124)
        at com.example.ex.utilities.DrawingSurface.draw(DrawingSurface.java:133)
        at com.example.ex.utilities.DrawingThread.onSurfaceUpdate(DrawingThread.java:95)
        at com.example.ex.utilities.DrawingThread.run(DrawingThread.java:46)
```

The `draw()` method of the `SurfaceView` is called by a separate `Thread`:

```
public class DrawingThread extends Thread {
    volatile boolean mRunning = false;

    private long mRefreshRate;
    private DrawingSurface mSurface;

    public DrawingThread (DrawingSurface surface, long time) {
        super();
        mSurface = surface;
        mRefreshRate = time;
    }

    public void setRunning (boolean run) {
        mRunning = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (mRunning) {
            try {
                sleep(mRefreshRate);
                onSurfaceUpdate();
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(Configuration config, Point fit, float ratio) {
        float width, height;
        if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            width = fit.y * ratio;
            height = fit.y;
        } else if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            width = fit.x;
            height = fit.x / ratio;
        } else {
            width = fit.x;
            height = fit.x / ratio;
        } mSurface.getHolder().setFixedSize((int) width, (int) height);
    }

    private void onSurfaceUpdate() {
        Canvas canvas = null;

        try {
            canvas = mSurface.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (mSurface.getHolder()) {
                mSurface.draw(canvas);
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                mSurface.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried pausing the thread before the `LinkedList` is iterated in `setActiveSticker()` and resuming after the loop is finished in an attempt to avoid the both modifications from happening at the same time. Even though that does not seem to be recommended. I would like to know how I can iterate the `LinkedList` without this error, or if there is a better way of achieving the same functionality.

Comment: It's generally unwise to override `draw()` or `onDraw()` when working with a SurfaceView -- that will draw on the View part when the app framework gets an invalidate. You want to be drawing on the Surface part. If you really do want to operate in the invalidate/refresh cycle, you should switch to a custom View. The fix is simple: rename the method and drop the `@override`.

Comment: @fadden How would I go about drawing on the 'Surface' part then? If I switch to a custom `View` then I also loose the convenience of the `SurfaceView` methods that interact with the thread.

Comment: @fadden I misunderstood, I thought you meant to rename and drop the `@Override` if I switched to a custom `View`. I renamed my `draw()` method to `drawSurface()` (and removed `super.draw(canvas)`), works perfectly, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Instead of iterating the `LinkedList`, an `Iterator`, or a `ListIterator` in `draw()`, which can all produce a `ConcurrentModificationException`, I converted the `LinkedList` to a simple array, like so:

```
Sticker[] stickers = mStickers.toArray(new Sticker[mStickers.size()]);
for(Sticker sticker : stickers) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(sticker.getBitmap(), sticker.getMatrix(), sticker.getPaint());
}
```

I also left `setActiveSticker()` method as I originally posted it, considering it was not producing any errors. I found the answer I was looking for in a small list of options titled *"To Avoid ConcurrentModificationException In [A] Multi-Threaded Environment"* in this article: [How To Avoid ConcurrentModificationException When Using An Iterator](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html).

**EDIT:**
My new draw method based on the tip from @fadden:

```
public void drawSurface(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mMatrix, mPaint);

    Sticker[] stickers = mStickers.toArray(new Sticker[mStickers.size()]);
    for (Sticker sticker : stickers) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(sticker.getBitmap(), sticker.getMatrix(), sticker.getPaint());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal. You can't change the underlying `Collection` while you are looping. You can use a [ListIterator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ListIterator.html) that has the add and remove items

```
private void setActiveSticker(float x, float y) {
    ListIterator<Sticker> stickersDesc = mStickers.descendingIterator();
    while (stickersDesc.hasNext()) {
        Sticker sticker = stickersDesc.next();
        if (sticker.collider(x, y)) {
            stickersDesc.remove();
            stickersDesc.add(sticker);
            mMode = MODE_DRAG;
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: But then how would I remove the items from the underlying `Collection` so that they are not drawn to the `Canvas`?

Comment: removing it from the Iterator removes it also from the Collection. In your logic you are adding it again. May I ask you why ?

Comment: I am trying to reorder the `LinkedList` so that the stickers are drawn with the `mActiveSticker` on top

Comment: I have switched to using a `ListIterator` for both `setActiveSticker` and `draw` but I am still getting a `ConcurrentModificationException`. The exception is thrown when I set `Sticker sticker = stickersDesc.next()` in the `draw` method.